# how to put double variable data in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i've case to use variable more the one like code bellow :

```js
function upload(iddata,ring)
{
  //variable 1
  dataString ="iddata="+iddata+"&ring="+ring+""; // variable 1
  
  //variable 2
  var formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
    var file = filesToUpload[i];
 formData.append("file[]", file, file.name);    
  }
  
  // i want put both variabel in ajax like this
  $.ajax({
    data: {formData,dataString}, //variable 1 and 2 in group
  });
}
```

please how source is True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle your whole `data` as an `object` only, and not mix it as a `string` and a `array` in a `object`. In this case you would not get the expected data in your receiver.

You could change it like this:

```
function upload(iddata, ring) {
    var data = {
        iddata: iddata,
        ring: ring,
        formData: new FormData()
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
        var file = filesToUpload[i];
        data.formData.append("file[]", file, file.name);
    }

    $.ajax({
        data: data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MyBird extends CI_Controller {

 /**
  * Index Page for this controller.
  
 function add_bird()
 {
  
  // get user id posted
  $iddata=empty($_POST['iddata']) ? '' : $_POST['iddata'];
  $ring=empty($_POST['ring']) ? '' : $_POST['ring'];
  
  //echo json_encode(array('uploaded' => 'Oke Bos'));
  if ( ! empty($_FILES))
  {
   $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/images/uploads";
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|mp4|ogv|zip';


   $this->load->library('upload');

   $files           = $_FILES;
   $number_of_files = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
   $errors = 0;

   // codeigniter upload just support one file
   // to upload. so we need a litte trick
   for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++)
   {
    $Random_Number      = rand(0, 9999999999); //Random number to be added to name.
    $NewFileName   = "Ring".$ring._.$Random_Number; //new file name

    $config['file_name'] = $NewFileName;
    $_FILES['file']['name'] = $files['file']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['type'] = $files['file']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['error'] = $files['file']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['size'] = $files['file']['size'][$i];

    // we have to initialize before upload
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (! $this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
     $errors++;
    }
   }

   if ($errors > 0) {
    echo $errors . "File(s) cannot be uploaded";
   }

  }
 }
}
```

in controller i put code like bellow, but the filen can't move upload